# Routable streets database

Tags: openstreetmap, data, pgrouting, address

I'm trying to find the most "affordable" way to have a routable database, and I'm having some questions that maybe some of you can clarify.

My aim is to store all data in our server (not external APIs) and use Postgres/PostGIS, so what I'm looking for is to download all the database.

I know some sources:

OSM: I should download all Europe and make it routable in order to use it with pgRouting, but my main doubt is the consistence of data. Does anybody know if there is any company that uses OSM data in a production server?

Michelin: The source we currently have. We access it through an API, and we want to change it due to high costs.

ArcGIS: I know that ArcGIS offers a routable street database, but I think is only an API, you can't download it.

Google: The same as ArcGIS, only offer data via API

Does anybody knows any other source for a routable street database?

Comment: Mapquest uses OSM http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapQuest

Answer (score 1):

For many yoears there have been already SEVERAL routing solutions based on OSM data. See the OSM wiki about [Routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) for an overview. Try all listed online or offline solutions, I recommend.

If you want professional advice or services, see [Commercial OSM Software and Services](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Commercial_OSM_Software_and_Services) where the biggest players about routing seem to be https://mapzen.com or https://www.mapbox.com or https://www.graphhopper.com or http://www.geofabrik.de to name but a few.

Check their individual portfolio of OSM based solutions.

I assume that you can derive from several mentioned websites which other companies make already use of OSM based routing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

OSM is without doubt the cheapest, but also the one with most errors in terms missing snap and such, but on the other hand it may have more details and be more up to date. All depending upon where in Europe you are. Even though errors are fixed on a constant basis, new ones also gets added all the time.

TomTom and HERE are the two big commercial offerings with higher quality and a standardized product. You may also consider AND (www.and.com).

Comment: It depends what sort of routing the OP wants to do, of course. TomTom and HERE certainly do not have higher quality than OSM for cycling or pedestrian routing.